# in R, finding the mean with number greater then in Dataset?

Tags: r, dataset, decimal, mean

Im doing a small question in R. the question is

"Look at the crabs dataset in the MASS library. Select only those crabs with a body depth greater than or equal to 10 mm. Get the mean carapace width of these crabs. Write the answer (to one decimal place) ".

In order to install  crabs dataset in R (RStudio).
You need to type

```
library(MASS)
crabs #or head(crabs)
? crabs #for more information about crabs dataset
```

Now I did a solution for the question that I provided above. Here's the code for the question

```
newcrab <- subset(crabs, BD >= 10) 
round(mean(newcrab$CW),1)
```

The answer is 38.3
But Im not sure if the answer is correct.

Can anyone help me if there is another way to find the correct answer using the crabs dataset?

[Solution is wrong, Click on link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpiDJ.jpg)

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with your answer. Do you have a specific doubt? A one-liner without creating a `newcrab` dataset  and without using `subset` is `round(mean(crabs[crabs$BD >= 10, "CW"]), 1)`.

Comment: well the answer I provided is wrong. I'm doing a quiz online  (This is for my college assignment).  I got a feedback but I can resubmit my answer again. I don't know why  the answer is wrong.

Comment: 38.3 is the correct answer. Did you provide this answer and still get the question wrong?

Comment: I did. I submit the answer "38.3"  twice but still the answer is wrong

Comment: If the question is right then your answer is right. The code in my first comment also gives the result 38.3.

Comment: Ok. there is some mistake with the google form quiz. I will ask my lecturer about the answer in college next day. Thanks for your feedback by the way

Comment: Your code looks fine, could the web form be expecting you to include units in your answer, so "38.3mm"?

Comment: Nope still incorrect answer using unit 38.3mm